# 2D display looks weird in OpenGL

Tags: qt, opengl

Currently I am writing a video player in OpenGL.

I call gluOrtho2D like this:

```
 gluOrtho2D(0, w, 0, h);
```

And output it with:

```
 glBegin(GL_QUADS);
      glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f(0, this->height());
      glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f(this->width(), this->height());
      glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.1f); glVertex2f(this->width(), 0);
      glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
 glEnd();
```

The correct output should be like:
[image: http://imgur.com/ssNUF]

But what I see is... (Please pay attention to the bottom right corner)

[image: http://i.imgur.com/vkx1K.png]

It seems that it's rendered incorrectly. Maybe you would recommend me to use sdl_opengl... But I'm currently using OpenGL in Qt, so I would not be able to open SDL windows.

So, what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it perhaps because you're using `1.1f` as the `y` part of the 3rd texture coordinate?